# understanding Google Identity Platform and OpenID connect

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth, openid-connect, google-identity

I'm using Google Identity Platform to connect my users using Email / Password, but I think of creating an oidc flow to connect my users into other applications.

I found this provider in Google Identity Platform :
[image: google identity platform]

Is this used to add a new oidc server or client ? and how to integrate it in the application ?

If you can please provide me a scenario or a use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The document shows how to use Identity Platform to sign in a user with an email and password [1]. You might also want to support additional sign-in methods, such as social providers (like Facebook or Google), phone numbers, OIDC, or SAML.

This link [2] is helpful for clear understanding on how to use Identity Platform to sign in users with an OpenID Connect (OIDC) provider.

For more details on registering client application with the OnenID provider I hope documentation [3] could be helpful.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quickstart-email-password

[2] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc

[3] https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/archive/1.1/how-to/security/oidc#register_with_provider